# Building a data driven UI

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, user-interface

I have searched throughout SO on this topic for iPhone and everything points to the WWDC 2010 coverage, so yes I'm aware of that. But can anyone point me to a more detailed resource from where I can learn how to build a robust system for presenting different user interfaces on an app depending on the data that I'm presenting? I am fetching the data in a JSON format and my UI needs to vary depending on what I get out of the JSON parser.

Any books or online resources that give a detailed look into this topic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had the same issue in one of my apps (navigation style) and the way I solved it is fairly simple.

I had a user_type flag in my JSON response, and depending on that flag I would push a different view controller.

For example, given my JSON response is stored in a NSMutableDictionary called "response"

```
if ([response objectForKey:@"account_type"] == 1) {
  /*
    initialize user_type 1 viewController
  */
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:userType1ViewController animated:YES];
else if ([response objectForKey:@"account_type"] == 2) {
  /*
    initialize user_type 2 viewController
  */
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:userType2ViewController animated:YES];
}
```

You can have as many different user_types as you want.

*Editing after clarification in comments*

You will likely be manually drawing these views.

I would subclass UIView for each of the different question types you have listed (including properties for common elements like question title, choices, etc). Assuming that questions with the same question type will have the same layout.

Then you can cycle through your JSON response (once it's in an array or dictionary) and lay it out.

If it's a multiple choice question, make a new multipleChoiceQuestion view, add its properties, then addSubview to the main feed view. Then, for your next view, you will need to set the frame to be:

```
nextQuestion.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 + firstQuestion.frame.size.height, height, width);
```

This will ensure that your second question is drawn right below the first question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But my needs are a bit more complicated. I at any point of time would have no idea what to expect from the response as far as the quantity of data is concerned. I have Q&A's coming in the response for which I've decided on textViews. Rating scales coming in for which I've setup UISliders. Multiple option Q&A's coming in and I've got UITableViews/UIPickerViews. But I will know how many of each only when I parse the response. How do I layout my view accordingly?

Comment: Am I clear? In case if I'm not its like this. I may receive any number of Q&A items in the response AND of any type (multi-choice,rating scale,simple Q&A). I won't know that until the parsing is done. Only then will I know how many textviews, sliders and tables or pickers to setup. Its not the question of loading fixed different view controllers based on simple decisions. Its more about laying out the different subviews on the viewcontroller based on the response. I may need to setup 1 one of each type, or just 1 textview or I may need 10 textviews, 5 sliders and 3 tables. Got it?

Comment: edited my response. Let me know if this helps. Are you comfortable with subclassing UIView and drawing things manually in drawRect?

Comment: Neat. Let me give it a shot and then I'll accept the answer when I'm done :) +1 for the great help. Thanks. I thought the solution was similar too but just wanted to know if there existed any other robust ways to get things done more efficiently. Cheers!